# Assign a temp variable rather than use properties many times

Tags: c#

If I need to use an inner property few times in a scope like:

```
var A= student.Course.StartTime;
var B= student.Course.EndTime;
var C = student.Course.Location;....
```

Would you assign a temp variable like:

```
var course = student.Course;
```

tx.

Comment: Depends on the `getter` in `property` and what is your end goal.

Comment: Yes, but I'd call it something like `studentCourse` so the comprehension context isn't lost (we know it's a course of a student, and not a course obtained from a list of all available courses).

Comment: Just a getter that exposes private member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be good reasons to do this:

- **Consistency** - if there is a possibility that `Course` would return different value on a subsequent invocation, perhaps because it could be set concurrently, local variable is necessary.
- **Readability** - adding a variable with easy-to-understand name can shorten the code, and tends to make the code easier to read.
- **Computed Properties** - if a property requires long computation or a trip to a database, with no caching (it's someone else's module), adding a local variable will improve performance.

On the other hand, introducing a local variable in an attempt to save a few CPU cycles is premature micro-optimization, which should be avoided.

Comment: wish Visual Studio showed this when running Code Analyzer.